# Blender 2.90.1 - Random errors while baking actions from a rigify rig to a separate, game-ready rig

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

Recently I started noticing these itty bitty random errors when I bake my animations to a rig made using Game Rig Tool. Like, bone rotations and/or locations will be slightly wrong. As mentioned, this only started happening recently. Before I post more details I just wanted to ask if there's such a thing as .blend file rot? As in, .blend files accumulate more and more gunk the bigger they get and then they start to go erratic like this one seems to do?

This is starting to drive me a bit nuts so I'd really appreciate any thoughts or ideas on what might be going on.

Comment: Hey, this is CGDive :) Since this is a problem is with Game Rig Tools, feel free to send me a file I can test. I guess you could say that blend files do "accumulate gunk" in some ways but it shouldn't cause incorrect results. If it does, there is a problem that needs to be fixed.